# How to refresh page after filtering or mapping in javascript

Tags: javascript, api

I need to create a contact list with data from an API of random people. My page has a simple form (input + button) then after click should show a new list or filtered data from last list if there is some input text. The data is being fetch correctly and recorded into localStorage (limited to 10 users).

The problem: data is being added to the page instead of refreshing into the page.

How can I  have new data on page for every click?

```js
async function fetchPeople() {
  const URL = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10';
  const res = await fetch(URL);
  let data = await res.json();
  return data;
}

async function data(name) {
  let filteredData = [];

  if (name.length > 0) {
    let newdata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('contacts'));
    filteredData = newdata.filter((contact) => {
      return contact.name.first.toLowerCase().includes(name);
    });
  } else {
    let data = await fetchPeople();
    localStorage.setItem('contacts', JSON.stringify(data.results));
    filteredData = data.results;
    return filteredData;
  }
  return filteredData;
}

async function printData() {
  let ul = document.querySelector('#cards');
  let name = document.querySelector('#contact').value.toLowerCase();
  let filteredData = [];

  filteredData = await data(name);

  filteredData.forEach((contact) => {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = `
      <div class="card">
        <img src="${contact.picture.large}"
          alt="${contact.name.first} ${contact.name.last}"
          class="card__image">
        <h2 class="card__name">${contact.name.first}  ${contact.name.last}</h2>
        <p class="card__email">${contact.email}</p>
        <p class="card__location">${contact.location.city}-${contact.location.state}</p>
        <button class="card__btn">${contact.location.country}</button>
      </div>`;
    ul.appendChild(li);
  });
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section class="form">
  <div class="search">
    <h1>Contact List</h1>
    <div class='search__field'>
      <input type="text" name="contact" id="contact" placeholder="Nome do contato" class="search__name form-control">
      <button type="button" onclick='printData()' class='btn btn-primary search__btn'>Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="results">
  <ul class="cards" id="cards"></ul>
</section>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**JSFiffle**
https://jsfiddle.net/w7gknc2t/

Comment: I suggest you create a functional snippet with the HTML, CSS and JavaScript of that code in the fiddle right here in your question

Comment: The fiddle is on the bottom please check

Comment: The point of my comment is to take that code and put it right in your question.

Comment: I created a snippet to get you started - needs the CSS perhaps.

Comment: JSFiffle https://jsfiddle.net/w7gknc2t/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear ul innerHTML before appending new data.

```js
async function printData() {
  let ul = document.querySelector('#cards');
  let name = document.querySelector('#contact').value.toLowerCase();
  let filteredData = [];
  
  filteredData = await data(name);
  ul.innerHTML = '';
  
  filteredData.forEach((contact) => {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = `
      <div class="card">
        <img src="${contact.picture.large}"
          alt="${contact.name.first} ${contact.name.last}"
          class="card__image">
        <h2 class="card__name">${contact.name.first}  ${contact.name.last}</h2>
        <p class="card__email">${contact.email}</p>
        <p class="card__location">${contact.location.city}-${contact.location.state}</p>
        <button class="card__btn">${contact.location.country}</button>
      </div>`;
    ul.appendChild(li);
  });
}
```